# Add 'Right Now' widget to custom dashboard

Tags: customization, widgets, metabox, dashboard

I have created a custom dashboard page to which the user is redirected when logged in. I want to include the 'Right Now' widget to my custom dashboard page. How do I achieve that ?

```
class CustomDash {

function __construct(){

    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( &$this, 'nn_register_custom_dash' ) );
    add_action( 'load-index.php', array( &$this, 'nn_redirect_custom_dash' ) );
}

function nn_register_custom_dash(){

    add_dashboard_page( 'Custom Dash', 'Custom Dash', 'manage_options', 'custom-dash', array( &$this, 'nn_create_dash' ) );
}

function nn_redirect_custom_dash(){

    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( $screen->base == 'dashboard' )
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'index.php?page=custom-dash' ) );
}

function nn_create_dash(){


}
}

new CustomDash();
```

Comment: Do you call `wp_dashboard()` in your custom page?

Comment: Nope ! Is it deprecated ? Could not find it on codex !

Comment: Show us what you did and how you did it -> in Code.

Comment: My bad. Edited for better clarity !

Comment: Take a look at how it's implemented in core: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php#L38.

Also take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_dashboard_widget if you haven't already. You may need to look into duplicating the widget for re-use in your page if you can't call it directly.

Comment: Hi Morgan this works well for custom dashboard page wherein the URL remains the same i.e. index.php. But not in the case where a dashboard page has been added and URL for dashboard now is 'index.php?page=custom-dash' (as posted in the code above)

Answer (score 1):

I've got to know it in [Make WordPress UI](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2013/08/30/dashboard-plugin-update/). The plugin [Dashboard](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dashboard/) uses a very interesting technique:

```
add_action( 'load-index.php', array( $this , 'override_dashboard' ) );

public function override_dashboard() 
{
    if( !isset( $_GET['page'] || 'custom-dash' != $_GET['page'] )
        return;

    if ( get_current_screen()->in_admin( 'site' ) ) {
        require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/dashboard-override.php';
        exit;
    }
}
```

And then it proceeds to fully rebuild the Dashboard with the file [`dashboard-override.php`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/dashboard/trunk/dashboard-override.php), with a brand new clones of the Widgets, like [`rightnow.php`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/dashboard/trunk/rightnow.php). I think it's worth emulating.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Will try to implement and let you know the results!

Comment: Hi @brasofilo this works well for custom dashboard page wherein the URL remains the same i.e. index.php. But not in the case where a dashboard page has been added and URL for dashboard now is 'index.php?page=custom-dash' (as posted in the code above)

Comment: Try with the edited code. I'm not sure about `get_current_screen()`, test if it's the correct check.